# 2 columns from Pipe delimited 5columns using regex in java

Tags: java, regex

3 columns from Pipe delimited 7columns using regex in java

Example:

```
String:
10|name|city||date|0|9013
```

i only want upto city(3 columns):

Expected output:

```
10|name|city
```

means: i want number of columns based on `|` using regex.

Thank you.

Comment: I am missing your attempt. If you have chosen regex as the approach to that solution, where is your regex?

Comment: i was trying with this regex: "^(\\|){3}[^|]*$"

Comment: that does not take the characters between the pipes into account...

Comment: It's a String, so you should be able to use `stringVariableName.split("\\|")` to get an array of all the columns splits based on the `|` value. From there, just use the first three values of the array it returns.

Comment: i was showing error as : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found

Comment: i need a string with all the |, just want to cut the columns
in future if i am getting 55 columns and need only 40 columns then using regex i should solve the issue , otherwiser i have to make the string again, same thing need to apply for each of the row.

Comment: @satya How exactly are you managing your data for this project? Because it sounds like you might be better off using a 2 dimensional ArrayList to store individual values instead of keeping the data in Strings since you plan to disassemble and assemble the data regularly.

Comment: it is a ("|")delimited file, which may contain many rows.

Comment: Yeah, I would recommend breaking the data up into a 2D ArrayList then for easier access and management of the data when you import it from the file into your program. Once it's in the 2D ArrayList, it will be much easier to access the data based on an arbitrary number of rows and columns or assemble it back into a String.

Comment: below is the example:
60020312|20140316163522|20151201093452|60020312|0|1
60020332|20140316180933|20151128193050|60020332|0|1
60020228|20140313061407|20150909062545|60020228|0|1
60020313|20140315203834|20150402211523|60020313|0|1
60020241|20140312173007|20150412211619|60020241|0|1
60020242|20140312173629|20150311211304|60020242|0|1
60020243|20140312183150|20150616162733|60020243|0|1
60020282|20140319130114|20150225184950|60020282|0|1

Answer (score 1):

I would use a simple regex pattern with the split method. There's probably a more elegant way to handle the pipes in the resulting string but this should give you an idea, goodluck!

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     String str = "10|name|city||date|0|9013";
     // split the string whenever we see a pipe
     String[] arrOfStr = str.split("\\|");
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     // loop through the array we generated and format our output
     // we only want the first three elements so loop accordingly
     for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
       sb.append(arrOfStr[i]+"|");
     }
     // remove the trailing pipe
     sb.setLength(sb.length() - 1);
     System.out.println(sb.toString());
  }
```

Comment: i want to do using a regex, so in future column size is increase also i do not have problem, like instead of 7 columns total columns will be 55 and need 40 columns out of that

Comment: same need to do far all other row as well

Comment: String.split() takes regex as an argument. So the "\\|" is actually a regex pattern. If you need to get more than 3 columns change the value of 3 in the loop to what you need. Read the comments in the code I posted.

Comment: I misread your comment, you should include that info that there are more rows in your input. In that case, you should use a 2d array, the rest of the code can be similar to the snippet I posted, just use a double for loop and make changes accordingly.

Comment: @rhowell Seems like they will have an unknown number of rows in their data set, so they would probably want to use an ArrayList of String[], or a 2D ArrayList if they plan to change the number of columns at any point.

Comment: @TimHunter yea sounds about right, thanks for sharing